# Using a Class variable in a method/function creates a reference to the source not duplicates it?

Tags: java, android, class

I'm asking if I create a Custom Class object with say 100 integer values in it.

If I were to pass that variable into a method that contains and object of the same type I am only passing a refernce to the source object, I'm not making a duplicate of those 100's of variables, right?

```
  class BigClass {
    int A;
    int B;
    ...
  }

   BigClass ThisClass = new BigClass();


   private void DoSomething(BigClass b) {
          BigClass ThatClass = b; 
   }


   **************

   DoSomething(ThisClass);
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) may interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, just the reference to the instance of your class will get passed/copied. The actual guts of your class will not be copied.

See Jon Skeet's article about [parameter passing in Java](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html), it does a good job of explaining things.

Comment: Thank you for no "mumbo jumbo" :)

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. When you pass objects to another class, you are simply passing a reference to it.